# Alguien que me ayude a revisar un código en Python. Son tres errores que no he podido encontrar

Tags: python, depuración

Tengo tres problemas con el siguiente código.

Se supone que debe calcular una cierta cantidad de puntos de distribución, pero arroja una unidad menos de lo esperado.

Por otro lado, si el contador es mayor a 100 debería imprimir una alarma y lo esta haciendo como si fuera mayor o igual a 100.

Tampoco me esta arrojando las impresiones del `If` del total de cajas igual a 0, como si nunca quedara en 0 la variable del total de cajas.

```
def controldecamion(time, cajas):
    totalCajas = 2000
    distribucion = int (totalCajas / cajas)
    conteoCajas = cajas
    
    for puntoDistribucion in range (1, distribucion + 1):
        totalCajas = totalCajas - conteoCajas
        if totalCajas < cajas: 
            conteoCajas = totalCajas
        print(f"Punto de distribución # {puntoDistribucion}")
        
        for contador in range (1, conteoCajas + 1):
            print(f"Caja # {contador}")
            contador = contador + 1
            if contador > 100:
                print("Encender alarma")
        if time > 15:
            print ("Se excede el limite de tiempo")
        if totalCajas == 0:
            print(f"Se ha agotado el inventario en el camnión")
            print(f"El total de cajas en inventario en el camnión = {totalCajas}")
            print(f"Cantidad de cajas despachadas = {conteoCajas}")
            print(f"Tiempo de despacho = {time}")
        else:
            print(f"El total de cajas en inventario en el camnión = {totalCajas}")
            print(f"Cantidad de cajas despachadas = {conteoCajas}")
            print(f"Tiempo de despacho = {time}")

controldecamion(10, 102)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se supone que debe calcular una cierta cantidad de puntos de
> distribución, pero arroja una unidad menos de lo esperado

```
distribucion = int (totalCajas / cajas)
```

Bueno, 2000 / 102 da 19 puntos de distribución. Tal vez deberías calcular:

```
from math import ceil

distribucion = ceil (totalCajas / cajas)
```

> Por otro lado, si el contador es mayor a 100 debería imprimir una
> alarma y lo esta haciendo como si fuera mayor o igual a 100.

```
for contador in range (1, conteoCajas + 1):
            print(f"Caja # {contador}")
            contador = contador + 1
            if contador > 100:
                print("Encender alarma")
```

El problema es que primero imprimes contador, luego le sumas 1 y después haces el `if`.

Entonces, cuando imprimes

```
Caja # 100
```

`contador` está en 100, le sumas 1 y lo dejas en 101. Luego tienes el `if` con el contador en 101, ergo, imprime el mensaje.

```
if contador > 100:
   print("Encender alarma")
```

> Tampoco me esta arrojando las impresiones del if` del total de cajas
> igual a 0

Si agregas un print() justo antes del `if`, veras que nunca llega a 0. Su último valor es 62. Me resulta díficil seguir la lógica del conteo, pero eso es lo que produce.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, estoy aprendiendo y a veces la lógica me gana un poco, voy a revisar los puntos que me indicas.

Comment: Siguiendo tus buenos consejos logre corregir el código, muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo bastante con estos ejercicios.